# Changing link targets on DotNetNuke test site

Tags: dotnetnuke

In the past our DotNetNuke site was managed by a third party vendor.  Recently, my company recently decided to take over maintenance of our site.  They copied our dnn site from the production server to a test server so those of us who would be tasked with the maintenance would be able to "learn" without screwing up the production site.  No one at my company has any significant experience with dnn, so while this might seem like a very basic issue, we are all flying by the seat of our pants on this one.

We managed to get things functioning on the test server enough that we can navigate to the default page. The url for our test site is something like "test.ourdnnsite.com".  The production url is "www.ourdnnsite.com".  However, when we click "Login" we are directed to the login page of the production version (http://ourdnnsite.com/AccountLogin/tabid/217/Default.aspx).

So what have we not done?  Where are the the urls for the links set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim,

Which version of DNN are you running? You should be able to change the portal alias url in the database.

You are looking for [PortalAlias].[HTTPAlias]. Newer versions of DNN may use the [PortalSettings] table as well.

It may be helpful to find a find and replace script to search the database for the old url in all html modules and such as well.

Be sure to make a backup prior to any changes.